# I want to delete "(not in PATH env variable)" displayed when zsh launch

Tags: shell, zsh

I want to delete "(not in PATH env variable)" displayed when zsh launch.

When I login zsh, "(not in PATH env variable)" is displayed like the attached image.

What should I do to delete this message?[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing software_. Questions about interactive environment configuration should be at [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: That said, if you want to track down which line of code it came from, run `zsh -x -l -i` and read the trace logs it spits out to find the line right before that command. Unlike bash (where you need to set an appropriate value to `PS4` to get the source file and line number in the xtrace logs), `zsh -x` will log enough information to let you find the offending line out-of-the-box.